# How to have same formatting in flutter as in the webapp?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a flutter app for my webapp. The data source is the API. I am able to pull the data and display as required. However, the formatting is not right for the same data source. This is my code to write the data. I have shown how it looks on the mobile web (chrome) and how it appears on the app. Could you please why the "mm" in the options are going to next line for the same data ? Also how to replicate the same formatting in the app?

```
class QuestionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int questionID;

  QuestionTile({Key key, this.questionID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuestionTileState createState() => _QuestionTileState(questionID);

}

class _QuestionTileState extends State<QuestionTile> {
  final int questionID;
  String optionSelected = "";

  _QuestionTileState(this.questionID);
  int _selectedValue;

  //int value;
  int ind;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuizProvider quizP = Provider.of<QuizProvider>(context);
    print(widget.questionID);
   
    return Container(child: Column(
      children:<Widget> [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Html(
                    data: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].content,
                    defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black, fontFamily: 'system-ui'),
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        
        quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions.length == null
            ? Container(
          child: Center(child: Text("Opps , Looks like we don't have any questions"),),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, itemCount) {
           return RadioListTile(
              value: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].id,
              groupValue: _selectedValue,
              onChanged: (answer){
                print(quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].id);
                setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = answer;               
                });
              },
              title: Text("${ quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].content.toString()}"),

            );
          },
        ),
      ],

    ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Raw Data:

```
"id": 5889,
                "content": "<p>An oil drop of 12 excess electrons is held stationary under a constant electric field of 2.55 x 10<sup>4</sup>N/C in Millikan&rsquo;s oil drop experiment. The density of oil is 1.26g/cc, g = 9.81m/s<sup>2</sup> and e = 1.60 x 10<sup>-19</sup>C. The radius of the drop is:</p>\r\n\r\n<p>(A) 9.82mm</p>\r\n\r\n<p>(B) 9.82 x 10<sup>-2</sup> mm</p>\r\n\r\n<p>(C) 9.82 x 10<sup>-4</sup> mm</p>\r\n\r\n<p>(D) 9.82 x 10<sup>-6</sup> mm</p>\r\n<gdiv></gdiv>",
                "getanswers": [
                    {
                        "id": 16134,
                        "content": "A",
                        "correct": false,
                        "question_id": 5889
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16135,
                        "content": "B",
                        "correct": false,
                        "question_id": 5889
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16136,
                        "content": "C",
                        "correct": true,
                        "question_id": 5889
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16137,
                        "content": "D",
                        "correct": false,
                        "question_id": 5889
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Can you add the raw data input that you are giving to Html widget? I assume you are using flutter_html. It seems like the problem is with the caret sign (^).

Comment: Yes. It seems that is the problem. I have added the raw data for you reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting issues were resolved in flutter_html: ^2.0.0